# Get $parent variables with ng-change() from nested selects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, components

I've got a code working well on firefox, but not working on chrome .

People want me to make it working on chrome but it is not working .

So this is the firefox working code :

```
<li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="element in $ctrl.filtres"> 
            <b>Mon critère numéro {{$index}} :</b><br>

             <select ng-model="element.champs"  class="form-control" > 
                <option value="">Champs</option>
                <option  ng-repeat ="champs in $ctrl.table"  ng-click="$ctrl.verify_data_type(champs,$parent.element)" >{{champs.column_name}}</option>
            </select>


            <select ng-model="element.operateur" class="form-control"  >
                <option value="">Opérateur</option>
                <option ng-repeat ="operateur in $ctrl.operateurs" value="{{operateur.nom}}" >{{operateur.traduction}}</option>
            </select>

            <input ng-if="element.showText"     ng-model="element.critere"      type ="text"    class="form-control" placeholder="Votre recherche"      title="Entrez plusieurs critères avec des virgules" required></input>
            <input ng-if="element.showDate"     ng-model="element.critere"      type ="date"    class="form-control" placeholder="Une date"             required></input>
            <input ng-if="element.showInteger " ng-model="element.critere"      type ="number"  class="form-control" placeholder="Un nombre"            required></input>
        </li>
```

There is a nested select, who must fire a verify_data_type function, in the purpose of showing the correct element.critere HTML input according to the data_type...

it is working very well in firefox .

This is the angularJs who does tha switch :

```
this.verify_data_type = function(champs,parent){

            switch(champs.data_type) {
                case 'integer':
                    parent.showInteger = true;
                    parent.showDate = false;
                    parent.showText = false;
                    break;
                case 'date':
                    parent.showInteger = false;
                    parent.showDate = true;
                    parent.showText = false;
                    break;
                case 'character varying':
                    parent.showInteger = false;
                    parent.showDate = false;
                    parent.showText = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    parent.showInteger = false;
                    parent.showDate = false;
                    parent.showText = true;
            } 



        }
```

Now, I am trying to do a code that works on CHROME, so i'm removing the ng-click and using ng-change instead :

```
<li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="element in $ctrl.filtres"> 
            <b>Mon critère numéro {{$index}} :</b><br>

             <select ng-model="$ctrl.champs"  class="form-control" ng-change="$ctrl.verify_data_type($parent)"> 
                <option value="">Champs</option>
                <option  ng-repeat ="champs in $ctrl.table"  ng-value="champs" >{{champs.column_name}} {{$parent}}</option>
            </select>


            <select ng-model="element.operateur" class="form-control"  >
                <option value="">Opérateur</option>
                <option ng-repeat ="operateur in $ctrl.operateurs" value="{{operateur.nom}}" >{{operateur.traduction}}</option>
            </select>

            <input ng-if="element.showText"     ng-model="element.critere"      type ="text"    class="form-control" placeholder="Votre recherche"      title="Entrez plusieurs critères avec des virgules" required></input>
            <input ng-if="element.showDate"     ng-model="element.critere"      type ="date"    class="form-control" placeholder="Une date"             required></input>
            <input ng-if="element.showInteger " ng-model="element.critere"      type ="number"  class="form-control" placeholder="Un nombre"            required></input>
        </li>
```

Unfortunatly, i can't get $parent to make it work any more and make my input show , this is the angularJs function :

```
this.verify_data_type = function(parent){


            switch(this.champs.data_type) {
                case 'integer':
                    parent.showInteger = true;
                    parent.showDate = false;
                    parent.showText = false;
                    break;
                case 'date':
                    parent.showInteger = false;
                    parent.showDate = true;
                    parent.showText = false;
                    break;
                case 'character varying':
                    parent.showInteger = false;
                    parent.showDate = false;
                    parent.showText = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    parent.showInteger = false;
                    parent.showDate = false;
                    parent.showText = true;
            } 
        }
```

I can see a $parent object in the console, but it is not working any more.

I've tried this : parent.element.showInteger = false for example with no luck, I've tried parent.this.element.showInteger  = false, it doesnt work either ...

If you have any idea, i would greatly appreciate it .

Comment: have you tried using `ng-options`? (you might not need `$parent`)

Comment: OK, but the inputs are inside various  parent  ng-repeat element(objects) repetitions ...